# Объясните о видимости класса в PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, ооп, классы, wordpress-плагины

Mало опыта с PHP, да и с ООП в целом, но вот делаю модуль для WordPress и столкнулся с такой интересной особенностью, как видимость классов в других файлах и никак не могу понять, как это работает.

Есть файл, в котором вызывается метод класса. Предварительно класс подключен через require_once, тут все окей, все понятно.

```php
require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/class-reloadly-products-activator.php';
Reloadly_Products_Activator::activate();
```

Дальше появляется такая конструкция:

```php
$plugin = new Reloadly_Products();
$plugin->run();
```

При этом сам класс Reloadly_Products() находится в другом файле и в другой папке.

Можете просто объяснить, почему одни классы нужно подключать, другие - нет, чем они отличаются и т.д.? Или кинуть ссылку на такую интересную вещь.

Comment: @splash58 Какая разница, использует WP namespace или нет. Все сложные плагины используют namespace.

Comment: ничем не отличаются, второй класс загружается где-то, например, в дебрях кода первого подключенного.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классы становятся доступны PHP с того момента, как содержащий их файл подключен с помощью include или require. В дальнейшем для использования уже подключенных классов можно использовать просто `new SomeClass();`.

Comment: Извините пожалуйста, у меня видимо взгляд очень замылен, действительно, я не увидел подключения файлов!
вопрос снимается, спасибо огромное!)